# Windows could not start mongodb service on local computer. For more info., review the System Event Log

Tags: mongodb, database

I am using `Windows 32-bit machine` and tried to start MongoDB service from **Windows > services** as shown below.

[image]

However, I am unable to start the MongoDB service from it and throws the following error.

[image]

When I try using cmd prompt, I am getting the following error:

> Network Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:10061 No
>   connection could be made because the target machine actively refused
>   it.
>
> Error: Couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 <127.0.0.1>,
>   connection attempt failed.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried installing the hot fix [KB2731284](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2731284) ?

Answer (score 16):

I had same an issue.

Try to remove **mongod.lock** file from your Mongo data directory.

For example mine is "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Data\mongod.lock" and after deleting file start the MongoDB service and it's work like charm.

Comment: I found it here: C:\mongodb\data\db.  I read the log files as suggested below and saw this: 2018-03-27T14:14:17.296-0700 [initandlisten] ERROR: Insufficient free space for journal files
2018-03-27T14:14:17.296-0700 [initandlisten] Please make at least 3379MB available in C:\mongodb\data\db\journal or use --smallfiles
2018-03-27T14:14:17.296-0700 [initandlisten]

Answer (score 7):

In case someone else is running into this problem, just read your Log files and you will be able to find the problem, for me after trying to install it inside wamp directory when I run the MongoDB service it gave me the same error message, I went to the logs and find out that I was missing a directory inside my data directory which is called `db`, once I have created this directory the service run perfectly.

Comment: Thanks this helped me. Turns out in my conf, the directory pointing to the logs file didnt exist on my machine, and i needed to set it to where my logs were located.

Answer (score 4):

MongoDB uses a default folder to store its files. On Windows, the default location is `C:\data\db`.

Maybe that folder doesn´t exist. In that case just creat it or change the default location of Mongo service using the `--dbpath command-line` flag.

Comment: When I tried running `net start MongoDB` I had this error: `The MongoDB service is starting. The MongoDB service could not be started. A service specific error occurred: 100. More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 3547.` I created `C:\data\db` and then when I ran  `net start MongoDB` it said `The MongoDB service is starting. The MongoDB service was started successfully.`

Comment: @WordsLikeJared Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 3):

So I just had the same problem, running on Windows 10. The reason why MongoDB didn't start was because the path to the data and logs was not correctly set. This has already been pointed out, but my solution is different. Look in `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin` (or wherever your mongoDB is installed). There is a config file called `mongod.cfg`. Check that

```
storage:
  dbPath:
```

and

```
systemLog:
  path:
```

Is set to what you want. In my case, it was using environment variables %MONGODBPATH% or similar that was not set by Windows. By default, the log and data should point to `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\data` and `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\log\mongod.log` respectively.

Answer (score 2):

mongod.lock deletion did not helped me, repair did not help either. In my case it was due to one of database happened to be corrupted, I moved all dbs to another directory and then copied them back one by one and re-starting mongodb service to figure out what db file is corrupted. It's definitely MongoDb bug

Answer (score 2):

There was a `npm:` in last line of mongodb configuration file which is located in the installation folder in the `bin\mongod.cfg`

I commented out that line and started the service and it is working like charm.

I concluded this by running the mongodb service command from windows command line(cmd) and I got an error.

I ran this to spot the error:

`C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin\mongod.exe --config "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin\mongod.cfg" --service`

Comment: in my case there was an ` itLog:` at the end of the config file. commenting that out did the trick.

Comment: Mine had `mp:`. Commenting it got the service running correctly.

Answer (score 1):

stuck on the same issue, but got the solution by hit and trial, just create a new folder for path "C:\data\db" then go to your command prompt and type 'mongod', your database server will start.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was a port problem :

just search and kill the process using the port 27017

for linux : https://bobcares.com/blog/mongodb-error-code-48/

for windows : [How do I kill the process currently using a port on localhost in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39632667/how-do-i-kill-the-process-currently-using-a-port-on-localhost-in-windows)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message. Try to locate the mongodb log files and look at the last entries. My issue was clearly stated there, a missing directory :

> 2019-01-29T16:59:44.424+0100 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in
>   initAndListen: NonExistentPath: Data directory
>   C:\wamp64\bin\mongodb\mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl-3.6.10\data\db
>   not found., terminating

Answer (score 0):

The advice of checking the log was what helped me. In this case:
*The MongoDB service could not be started. A service specific error occurred: 100*
turns out I had a problem with some databases created with WiredTiger while the mongod.cfg specified engine was: mmapv1
So I basically removed the content of the folder c:/data/db/ and then used the command net start MondoBD --repair and worked. Uffff it´s been 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

I'm here a bit late, very late actually. But may it works something out for the ones facing this issue now. Mongodb configuration file in Windows OS is under `'C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\%YOUR MONGO VERSION%'`.

I had changed this file and manipulated the bindip field, so I was getting the same error. It should be `127.0.0.1` or your machine's IP address which you can find it by `'ipconfig/all'` command in cmd. So I fixed bindip and the service starts with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out that Visual C++ Redistributable was missing in my Windows 7 Machine. After installing it worked.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 10 users
specify database location, if don't know create the below-mentioned directory and always use this

- open cmd

```
mkdir C:\users\{username}\data
cd C:\users\{username}\data
mongod --dbpath .
```

**start mongodb server**

- open cmd

```
mongod --dbpath C:\users\{username}\data
```

**stop mongodb**

- open cmd

```
mongo
```

if server is running, run:

```
use admin
db.shutdownServer()
quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this happened because I did not stop MongoDB from docker. after I stopped the process the error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was the docker with MongoDB running on the same port. So after I stopped the container, the service is then successfully starting.

Answer (score 0):

The log file pointed me towards this url
[MONGO DB Repair](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/tutorial/recover-data-following-unexpected-shutdown/)
but it didn't worked for me.
What worked for me was to give a new path to config file in **MongoDB Directory\Server\6.0\bin**

> storage:
> dbPath:(Give this a new path)

After that Start the MongoDB Server service from **services.msc** (in Windows).
It will work now. Will refresh your databases though :(

Answer (score 0):

Check the mongod.log file in installation (C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\7.0\bin)

and search dbpath loation.
"dbPath":"C:/data/db/"

make the folder same as you find in log file. then

try to start the mongodb service.

it will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsBjp.png)

I solved by opening task manager >> services >> find MongoDB >> restart